# using different prepositions in relation to a same period of time mentioned in different clauses

Tags: grammar, style

If I have already used preposition "during" in relation to one period of time in the first clause, can I use "in" in relation to a same period of time in the second clause?

For example,

She was quiet and even shy **during** the first semester, but became noticeably more active **in** the second one.

Or does it sound awkward and I better stick to "during" in both clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *during* for both would sound more awkward. English has a marvellous range of synonyms and near-synonyms for many words, and natural, flowing text usually **avoids repetition**. At least, up to a point. Text with a lot of repetition of words can seem either simplistic or legalistic.

Your use of *during* and then *in* is natural, and good style.